# Class which should "take over" ownership of another object by move does not work

Tags: c++, c++17, move

I am trying to develop a class which "contains" another class.  This contained class is move only because I want to represent that the resources that it refers to are uniquely managed by only one object at a time (for example, a hardware driver cannot be copied, but it could be moved).

Here is some of my test code:

```
#include <iostream>

static bool globalState = false;

class Driver {
public:
    Driver(bool& state) : 
        _state(state) 
    {
        std::cout << "Driver::Driver(bool&)" << std::endl;
        
        //Change the global state
        _state = true;
    }
    
    ~Driver() {
        std::cout << "Driver::~Driver()" << std::endl;
        
        _state = false;
    }

    //Copy constructor
    Driver(const Driver& other) = delete;
    
    //Copy Assignment
    const Driver& operator=(const Driver&) = delete;
    
    //Move Constructor
    Driver(Driver&& other) :
        _state(other._state)
    {
        std::cout << "Driver::Driver(Driver&&)" << std::endl;
    }
    
    //Move assignment
    Driver& operator=(Driver&& other) = default;
    
private:
    bool& _state;
};

class DriverUser {
public:
    DriverUser(Driver&& d) :
        _driver(std::move(d))
    {
        std::cout << "DriverUser::DriverUser()" << std::endl;
    }
    
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "DriverUser::foo()" << std::endl;
    }
    
private:
    Driver _driver;
};

void test() {
    std::cout << "Creating DriverUser..." << std::endl;
    //Driver d(globalState);
    //DriverUser user(d);
    DriverUser user(Driver(globalState));
    
    std::cout << "globalState should be 'true'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "globalState = " << (globalState ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    
    user.foo();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "globalState = " << (globalState ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "test()..." << std::endl;
    test();
    
    std::cout << "globalState = " << (globalState ? "true" : "false") << std::endl;
     
    return 0;
};
```

Where I am pretending that "globalState" is some resource that is going to be managed by my "Driver" class.  Where the "Driver" class can only be moved and not copied (because having two copies of a driver managing the same resource doesn't make sense).  Imagine DriverUser as a class which should "take ownership" of the associated Driver, thus why I am moving the Driver instance into DriverUser.

I am doing this with references because :

a) The Driver class ALWAYS has to refer to a valid resource (i.e., it can't be a pointer which points to no resource)

b) All of these classes should be created in a "static" fashion (i.e., I am no using new, unique_ptr, etc...)

In my example, with the line "user.foo()" commented out, everything compiles corretly but the output is not what I would expect

```
globalState = false
test()...
Creating DriverUser...
globalState should be 'true'
globalState = false
globalState = false
```

With that line enabled, I get the following compile-time error

```
In function 'void test()':
error: request for member 'foo' in 'user', which is of non-class type 'DriverUser(Driver)' user.foo();
```

Which makes absolutely no sense to me.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Nate Eldredge in the comments for pointing me to the fact that this is an example of the "Most Vexing Parse."

As a follow-up question, my code above seeks to demonstrate a problem I have with my own design where, If Driver is meant to manage a unique resource and thus the constructor "initializes" that resource and the destructor "de-initializes" that resource, because I am using a reference to the unique resource, moving Driver still keeps that reference around and thus, when the temporary Driver object is destroyed, it "de-initializes" the resource which is definitely NOT my intent.

My one solution would be to forget using a reference, use a pointer, and make sure the move constructor sets the pointer to nullptr.  Then, I would have to be checking for nullptr in all my Driver methods, which is not ideal.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: [Most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)?

Comment: as clang++ would tell you: `warning: parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
DriverUser user(Driver(globalState));` Use `{}` for initialization instead.

Comment: Add `bool is_owner = true;`. The move constructor sets `d.is_owner = false;` The destructor uses the `_state` only if `is_owner` is `true`. Put `assert(is_owner)` at the start of every member of Driver, so if somebody tries to use a moved-from Driver, they get an error. (But really, the way to do this is to use a `std::unique_ptr<State>` with a custom deleter. Then you get all the desired behavior for free. You say that you'll have to keep checking the pointer for nullptr, but even with the reference version, you'll have to keep checking `is_owner` so either way you're checking *something*.)

Answer (score 0):

If you stuck with this architecture, you can consider using:

1. [gsl::not_null< T > Class Template Reference](https://spectre-code.org/classgsl_1_1not__null.html)
2. [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

The first one better suits your need, the latter is common and a part of standard.